# Tourist visa Schengen Zone

Tags: italy, schengen-visas, 90-180-visa-rules

Trying to find the answer to this but all of the people I've contacted can't answer it.
So I entered the Schengen zone on June 11th and then left June 23rd.  Now I'm living in Italy until December 8th--I will reach 90 days as of the 8th of December.  Technically, 180 days from June 11th is December 7th.  Does that mean I get another 13 days in Schengen zone after the 7th?

How does this work with the rolling 180 days?

Comment: "I will reach 90 days as of the 8th of December": does this mean that you entered on September 10th or September 22nd?

Answer (score 2):

> How does this work with the rolling 180 days?

You entered on 11 June.  In the 180-day period that starts with 11 June, you can only be present for 90 days.  Of those 90 days, you used 13 with your first visit.  That leaves you with 77 days to use in the period from 24 June (the day after you left) to 7 December (the last day of the 180-day period that starts with 11 June).  This means that if you entered the Schengen area before 22 September, you will run out of days before the 180-day period ends, and your second visit will have to be shorter than 90 days (no more than 77 days, in fact).

If you entered on or after 22 September, your second visit can be up to 90 days long, because on any given day enough of your earlier presence will be more than 180 days old, so it will not count toward the 90-day total.

If the 90th day of your *current* visit is 8 December, that means you entered on 10 September.  If that's true, then you have to count your days in June, and your 90th day is 25 November.  In that case, you cannot stay in Italy until December, or even until 26 November.

If your 90th total day in the Schengen area is 8 December, that means you entered on 23 September, and you will hit the 90/180 limit on 21 December, so you must leave before the end of that day.

None of this applies, however, if you have a type-D Italian visa, because days of presence authorized by a type-D visa do not count for calculating the 90/180 rule.